# In React/ES6, is there a more concise way to write a ternary that references an attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my code right now, I have a bunch of code like this: `starterValue={ elementToEdit ? elementToEdit.size : null }`

I can't do `elementToEdit.size || null` or something like that because of `elementToEdit` isn't defined, it obviously can't get its attribute.

Is there a more concise way to write this or should I just deal? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `elementToEdit` is `null` when it isn't present, you can do

```
starterValue={ elementToEdit && elementToEdit.size }
```

If it is `undefined` or some other falsy value, that value will be passed through instead, but that's probably also fine in your usecase.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks. Is there a name for the && syntax other than something like an 'and and operator'

Comment: Nope, just a normal "and" operator with short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: short circuit evaluation was what I was looking for. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) :

```js
var obj = {
  size: 10
};

var {size} = obj;
console.log(size);

obj = null;
var {size} = obj || {}; // Note here we do not use null, but an empty object
console.log(size);
```

Answer (score 0):

A concise way to do this in JavaScript is using the [`get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) function from Lodash which yields `undefined` in a case the object is `null` or `undefined`, instead of throwing an error:

```js
var el1 = { size: 2 };
var el2 = null;

console.log(_.get(el1, 'size'));
console.log(_.get(el2, 'size'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to have `null` instead of `undefined`, you can use a third parameter for default value:

```js
var el1 = { size: 2 };
var el2 = null;

console.log(_.get(el1, 'size', null));
console.log(_.get(el2, 'size', null));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add a helper method and reuse it:

```
const getVal = (obj, key) => obj ? obj[key] : null
```

and then you could do `starterValue = getVal(elementToEdit, 'size');`

There are other tricks you can pull with [ES2015 proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) but those require you to have an outer object present.

So, if you were able to refactor your code to instead of having `elementToEdit` as the outer variable, but instead something like `const allElements = { elementToEdit };` Then you could use proxies to set the default value of elementToEdit.size to null if it's not present.

Answer (score 0):

If `elementToEdit` is already named but possibly undefined, you can just do:

`(elementToEdit && elementToEdit.size) || null`

If it's not named and no idea if it has subsequently been named/defined, you would have to do a typeof check in the same fashion:

`(typeof elementToEdit === 'object' && elementToEdit.size) || null`